# Modifying the datatype in SAS XML Map File

Tags: sas

I need to control the data type when reading XML data in SAS. The XML data are written and accessed using the XML libname engine in SAS.

**XML File :**

```
<Test>
   <origin>YYYY</origin>
   <NumToUse>50503</NumToUse>
   <AcctNum>3-219HHJLJ</AcctNum>
   <Status>1</Status>
   <TADIG>AUSVF</TADIG>
   <LocationNumber>1234567891011</LocationNumber>
   <Phnumber>1234567890</Phnumber>
   <ReferenceNumber>0044E71146</ReferenceNumber>
```

**Map File :**

```
    <COLUMN name="LocationNumber">
        <PATH syntax="XPath">/Test/LocationNumber</PATH>
        <TYPE>character</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
        <LENGTH>11</LENGTH>
    </COLUMN>

    <COLUMN name="PhNumber">
        <PATH syntax="XPath">/Test/PhNumber</PATH>
        <TYPE>character</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
        <LENGTH>15</LENGTH>
    </COLUMN>

    <COLUMN name="ReferenceNumber">
        <PATH syntax="XPath">/Test/ReferenceNumber</PATH>
        <TYPE>numeric</TYPE>
        <DATATYPE>double</DATATYPE>
    </COLUMN>
```

Since the Reference Number is treated as Numeric am not able get the value for that particular column .its giving me

```
ERROR: Data contains invalid content for float datatype. Invalid content is 0044E71146
```

How to read the data into SAS dataset ? suggestion pls

Comment: Am creating the MAP file usind SAS XML Engine  FILENAME XMLFILE "/v/temp/test.xml" ;
FILENAME MAPFILE "/v/temp/test.xml.map" ;

LIBNAME XMLFILE XMLV2 XMLTYPE=XMLMAP XMLMAP=MAPFILE AUTOMAP=REUSE ;

Comment: Let SAS create the map file ONCE.  Then edit it and fix the issue. Save the fixed version and use that from now on for this type of XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map file created by the `XMLV2` library can be modified before using the libref to copy data into your SAS session.

There are many ways to process the engine generated map file (which is an xml file itself)

- XSL transform (Proc XSL)

  - Someone (not me) well versed in XSLT language could likely write a short program to perform the modifications
- Programmatic manipulation of the parsed xml document
- Textual manipulation of the xml file

  - Hand editing
  - Text processing program

The **map file** :

- defines which xml nodes are to become data set columns

  - defines the type, length, format, label, etc, of the column
- defines which tables are to be created
- defines which tables are to contain which columns

For the case of wanting to change the XMLV2 engine's interpretation of numeric columns to character columns, the mapfile needs to be modified (aka *transformed*).

- `<COLUMN>` nodes have children nodes that, at a minimum, need to be changed
  from 
  `<TYPE>numeric</TYPE>` 
  to 
  `<TYPE>character</TYPE>`

**Considerations**

There are other considerations you might need to make when transforming numbers to character enmasse, such as:

- Is this numeric a date ?
- Should the number be rendered through it's format first ?

SAS users are comfortable with the concept of single 'data set' which contains both data and metadata (in the header).  For XML data, the data is in one file and the metadata (the mapfile) is in another.

When a SAS data that is exported and only the data xml is kept, the metadata gets lost.  Making the round trip back to SAS means the metadata must be guessed at via automap.

**Example code for "Programmatic manipulation of the parsed xml document"**

This example changes all column definitions for numeric columns to character. The XPath `/SXLEMAP/TABLE/COLUMN[not(@class='ORDINAL') and ./TYPE[text()='numeric']` is used to identify the column definitions that will be changed.  No further special considerations are made.

*Create xml data file to be processed*

```
%macro createXmlV2(data=,folder=);
  %local lib mem;

  %let syslast = &data;

  %let lib = %scan(&syslast,1,.);
  %let mem = %scan(&syslast,2,.);

  FILENAME XMLOUT  "&folder./&data..xml";

  LIBNAME XMLOUT XMLV2;

  proc copy in=&lib out=xmlout;
    select &mem;
  run;

  LIBNAME XMLOUT clear;
  FILENAME XMLOUT clear;
%mend;

%* Something to play with;
%* Create an XMLV2 generated xml file containing the data set;

%createXmlV2 (data=sashelp.citiday, folder=/temp)
%createXmlV2 (data=sashelp.citimon, folder=/temp)
%createXmlV2 (data=sashelp.baseball, folder=/temp)

%*;
```

*Transform automap file so numeric columns become character columns*

```
%macro prepXmlRefsFor(file=);
FILENAME XMLFILE "&file";
FILENAME MAPOUT  "&file..map";
FILENAME MAPOUT2 "&file..map.transformed";
%mend;

%prepXmlRefsFor(file=/temp/sashelp.citiday.xml)
%prepXmlRefsFor(file=/temp/sashelp.baseball.xml)
%prepXmlRefsFor(file=/temp/sashelp.citimon.xml)

%*;

%* create an automap file using XMLV2 library engine;

LIBNAME XMLFILE XMLV2 XMLTYPE=XMLMAP XMLMAP=MAPOUT AUTOMAP=REPLACE ;

%* parse and rewrite the generated map file ;
%* change ALL non-ordinal, non-character COLUMN nodes to indicate character type wanted;

proc groovy;
submit 
  "%sysfunc(pathname(MAPOUT))" 
  "%sysfunc(pathname(MAPOUT2))"
  "20" 
;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

// get parameter from submit line;

map_in=args[0];   // the automap
map_out=args[1];  // the automap transformed
length=args[2];   // length of character value for columns previously considered numeric

// parse mapfile;

doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(map_in);

xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

// select the set of automap nodes that define non-ordinal, numeric columns

columns = xPath.evaluate(
  "/SXLEMAP/TABLE/COLUMN" +
  "[" +
    "not(@class='ORDINAL')" +
    " and " +
    "./TYPE[text()='numeric']" +
  "]", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for (column in columns) {
  type = xPath.evaluate("TYPE",     column, XPathConstants.NODE);
  dtyp = xPath.evaluate("DATATYPE", column, XPathConstants.NODE);
  leng = xPath.evaluate("LENGTH",   column, XPathConstants.NODE);

  type.setTextContent("character");
  dtyp.setTextContent("string");

  if (leng == null)
    column.appendChild(leng = doc.createElement("LENGTH"));

  leng.setTextContent(length);
}

// rewrite mapfile with updated nodes

TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(
  new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(new File(map_out))
);

println "Programmatic transformation of mapfile completed.";
endsubmit;
quit;

* resubmit libname so libref uses transformed mapfile;

LIBNAME XMLFILE XMLV2 XMLTYPE=XMLMAP XMLMAP=MAPOUT2 AUTOMAP=REUSE;

proc copy in=xmlfile out=work;
run;

LIBNAME XMLFILE clear;
FILENAME XMLFILE clear;
FILENAME MAPOUT clear;
FILENAME MAPOUT2 clear;
```

One thing that became obvious after examining the 'round-trip' outcome is that xml files **created** by `XMLV2`, when re-read, will create **separate** column-named tables for any columns that contain missing values.  These tables would have to be merged to recreate the original data set.

Comment: Thanks  a lot !! it is simple to understand

Answer (score 1):

You might understand that the auto-mapping feature built into XMLV2 engine is choosing to define the ReferenceNumber as number, instead of as a character, is because the only one value the parser is examining is `0044E71146` and is presuming the `#E#` is scientific (or exponent) notation for a number.

The solution is to let the libname automap the data xml file and then update the map file xml to meet your requirements.

Example code:

`XMLV2` engine creates `MAPFILE`, and `Proc GROOVY` is used to XML parse and rewrite the mapfile.

```
FILENAME XMLFILE "/temp/test.xml" ;
FILENAME MAPFILE "/temp/test.xml.map" ;

* parse data test.xml and write mapfile test.xml.map;
LIBNAME XMLFILE XMLV2 XMLTYPE=XMLMAP XMLMAP=MAPFILE AUTOMAP=REPLACE ;

* parse and rewrite mapfile;
* change desired column nodes to be string/character of a specified length;

proc groovy;
submit "%sysfunc(pathname(mapfile))";
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

* get parameter from submit line;

mapfile=args[0];

* parse mapfile;

doc = DocumentBuilderFactory
      .newInstance()
      .newDocumentBuilder()
      .parse(
        mapfile
      )
      ;

xPath = XPathFactory
        .newInstance()
        .newXPath()
        ;

void setCharacter(column,length) {

  * find column node and child nodes important to XMLV2 mapfile usage;

  node = xPath.evaluate("/SXLEMAP/TABLE/COLUMN[@name='"+column+"']", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
  type = xPath.evaluate("TYPE",     node, XPathConstants.NODE);
  dtyp = xPath.evaluate("DATATYPE", node, XPathConstants.NODE);
  leng = xPath.evaluate("LENGTH",   node, XPathConstants.NODE);

  if (type != null && !type.getTextContent().equals("character")) { type.setTextContent("character") } 
  if (dtyp != null && !dtyp.getTextContent().equals("string"))    { dtyp.setTextContent("string") } 
  if (leng == null) {
    leng = doc.createElement("LENGTH");
    leng.setTextContent(length.toString());
    node.appendChild(leng);
  }
  else
  if (!length.getTextContent().equals(length.toString())) {
    leng.setTextContent(length.toString());
  }
}

// Make sure these two columns will be character, if not already

setCharacter("ReferenceNumber",25);
setCharacter("Phnumber", 20);

// rewrite mapfile with updated nodes

TransformerFactory
.newInstance()
.newTransformer()
.transform(
  new DOMSource(doc),
  new StreamResult(new File(mapfile))
);

endsubmit;
quit;

* resubmit libname so libref uses now updated mapfile;

LIBNAME XMLFILE XMLV2 XMLTYPE=XMLMAP XMLMAP=MAPFILE;

proc copy in=xmlfile out=work;
run;
```

Note: You could textually parse and rewrite the map file, however, there is a small outside chance the mapfile may not meet your 'text-parsing' expectations.

Comment: In you ex its mentioned  node = xPath.evaluate("/SXLEMAP/TABLE/COLUMN[@name='"+column+"']", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);  what is that /SXLEMAP/TABLE/COLUMN? can i use it directly in my code? sorry am neew to proc groovy

Comment: instead of setcharacter hardcoding column name ,is it possible to change all the tags to character ?

Comment: Yes, the power of XPath can return a list of nodes meeting the path criteria `/SXLEMAP/TABLE/COLUMN`.

Comment: Look at the MAPFILE created by XMLV2.  The node *nesting*, or hierarchical descent,  to the column specifiers defines the 'XPath'.  So SXLEMAP has children TABLE has children COLUMN.

Comment: Thanks, i got it . is there any way i can loop through all the elements in the MAP file created and change to STRING?

Answer (score 0):

Let SAS make the map file.

```
FILENAME XMLFILE "/v/temp/test.xml" ; 
FILENAME MAPFILE "/v/temp/test.xml.map" ; 
LIBNAME XMLFILE XMLV2 XMLTYPE=XMLMAP XMLMAP=MAPFILE AUTOMAP=REUSE ;
```

Edit the file and fix the definition

```
<COLUMN name="ReferenceNumber">
    <PATH syntax="XPath">/Test/ReferenceNumber</PATH>
    <TYPE>character</TYPE>
    <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
    <LENGTH>15</LENGTH>
</COLUMN>
```

You probably will want to save this in permanent and not a temporary location. Now use the fixed file to re-define the libref.

```
FILENAME XMLFILE "/v/temp/test.xml" ; 
FILENAME MAPFILE "/v/permanent/fixed_xml.map" ; 
LIBNAME XMLFILE XMLV2 XMLTYPE=XMLMAP XMLMAP=MAPFILE AUTOMAP=REUSE ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,it would work if  the column name is known ,for me the XML is dynamic and the column name will change for each run

Comment: Doesn't the generator of the XML supply you with the metadata needed to understand the XML?  That is critical information, especially if the XML changes over time.

Comment: No,they havent given us that XSD \